# Sending queries to neo4j through array via request.post

Tags: node.js, http, post, neo4j, callback

I am trying to insert queries in to neo4j from an array of queries depicted by 'arr' in node. I know that this array passes to the function as console.log(query) prints out a single query, I suspect its something to do with async, but i'm new to this so i'm baffled. The error i'm getting in the browser is "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

```
function runCypherQuery(arr,callback) {
  var query;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    query = arr[i];
    console.log(query);

      request.post({
            headers:{
              "Authorization": "Basic bmVvNGo6cGxleGlz"
            },
                  uri: httpUrlForTransaction,
                  json: {statements: [{statement: query}]}
       },function (err, res, body) {
            callback(err,res,body);               
      })
 }
}
```

I tried copying the same function without the loop to app.js with a single query and it managed to send no problem, like so

```
var query = "CREATE (u {id:573116})";

request.post({

  headers:{
    "Authorization": "Basic bmVvNGo6cGxleGlz"
  },
        uri: httpUrlForTransaction,
        json: {statements: [{statement: query}]}
    },
    function (err, res, body) {
          console.log(body);
})
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information, but it looks like the `request` variable is undefined because it is not within the scope of the `runCypherQuery` function. Try passing it in by changing the signature to something like:

```
function runCypherQuery(request, arr, callback)
```

and then pass the `request` when calling the function.

You should know that your code will asynchronously make the requests and that therefore there is no guarantee of order of execution. If you don't care, then this may not be a problem.

However, if you have a lot of separate Cypher queries in `arr`, then your code might be very inefficient, since there is overhead in making not only each HTTP request but also in starting and committing a transactions for each query. It would be better to try to merge queries, if possible and reasonable. For exampe, if you are just trying to create N nodes, you should be able to do that in a single query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The array is being created on the fly, so is returned from another function before this function is called. The array has a maximum of 60 and it doesn't matter what order they are executed in. I tried passing in the 'request' like you said, but i'm still getting the same error. Is it because 'request.post' shouldn't be inside a function as it is a node module? Is there any other way I can post the data without using a function?